# Mongoose - push array in deeply nested object

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to push an array of data obtained from a websocket into an object, in this case `oneMin`. That's where I'd like an array, not up above `kline` and under `bybit`

Here's what I'm seeing:

[image]

Here's the data model:

[image]

and here's the code I currently have:

```
ws.on('update', async function(message) {

  if (message.data !== null) {

    console.log(message)

    const Open = message.data[0].open;
    const High = message.data[0].high;
    const Close = message.data[0].close;
    const Low = message.data[0].low;
    const Volume = message.data[0].volume;
    const Timestamp = message.data[0].timestamp;

    const OHLCV = [Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, Timestamp]

    // var ohlc = new marketModel({ 
    //   bybit: {
    //             kline: {
    //               ethusd: {
    //                 oneMin: {
    //                   open: Open,
    //                   high: High,
    //                   low: Low,
    //                   close: Close,
    //                   volume: Volume,
    //                   timestamp:  Timestamp
    //                 },
    //               }
    //             }
    //           }
    // });
    // ohlc.push(function (data) {
    //   console.log("just saved to BTCUSDkline!");
    // });

    let setOHLCV = await marketModel.updateMany(
      {},
      {
        $addToSet: {
          bybit: {
            kline: {
              ethusd: {
                oneMin: {
                  open: Open,
                  high: High,
                  low: Low,
                  close: Close,
                  volume: Volume,
                  timestamp:  Timestamp
                },
              }
            }
          }
        },
      },
      {
        upsert: true,
        new: true,
      },
    );
    setOHLCV;
  }
});
```

I've been stuck on this one for a while now so any help would be thankful!

Thought I'd resort to SO for the first time in a while!

EDIT: So instead of `$addToSet`, `$setOnInsert` sets the data in the array under the object, one step closer! It doesnt even replace it, it just sets the first array given. Now I can say that `$Set` is like `$setOnInsert` but it replaces the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution, apparently I should've wrote it like this:

```
    let setOHLCV = await marketModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      {},
      {
        $push: {
          'bybit.kline.ethusd.oneMin': {            
            open: Open,
            high: High,
            low: Low,
            close: Close,
            volume: Volume,
            timestamp:  Timestamp
          }
        }
      },
      {
        upsert: true,
        new: true,
      },
    );
    setOHLCV;
  }
});
```